# How to generate country graphics?

Tags: svg, graphics, truetype, countries

I've got a pet project for which I need graphics of the outlines of certain countries (mostly European countries). I want to dynamically generate country graphics like the image below. Prefferably in a combination of JavaScript, HTML and CSS. I've been Googling for a bit and found: http://www.dafont.com/geobats.font.

It is near perfect, the sad thing is that there are missing a few countries. I have no clue how to edit TTF files so I'm not able to update it myself. I also lack the Photoshop skills to create the images I need by hand. So I was hoping you guys could help me out. Is there a site where I can get SVG's* of several countries of a TTF file such as geobats only with more (European) countries? Thanks in advance.

*In the case of SVG's I'd prefer cutouts over outlines.

**Update 1**: I've included an image to show which kind of graphics I'm trying to make.[image: example generated country graphic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Bostock is a map geek and has a separate project from [d3](http://d3js.org), [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki) with all kinds of sampling and projection features. This may be too much for your project, but he also has a blog post that talks about finding data while he demonstrates the topojson capabilities. The link is:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/#finding-data

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out.